# Calculating Divergence of a Composition of Vector Fields

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am attempting to compute the divergence of a composition of vector fields, though I am unsure of what to do.

Suppose we have a vector field $F(x,y,z) = (F_1(\textbf{x}), F_2(\textbf{x}), F_3(\textbf{x}))$ where $\textbf{x} = (x,y,z)$, such that $F_1, F_2, F_3 : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now one knows the definition of divergence gives $$\nabla \cdot F = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}$$

However, now suppose we have another function $A : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, which we can conveniently represent in matrix notation as $3 \times 3$ matrix.

What I am then wondering is how do we compute the divergence of $F \circ A$, where we see $F \circ A(x) = (F_1(Ax), F_2(Ax), F_3(Ax))$.

In order to compute this, I have tried to use the definition of the divergence and the chain rule together, but I never seem to get a scalar; I always have a matrix in the way, when a divergence should yield a scalar.
Thus I am wondering how do I apply the chain rule here to obtain the divergence?

In particular, how does one find $\nabla \cdot (F \circ A)$ ?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$\mathbf F(x,y,z) = F_1(x,y,z)\,\mathbf i + F_2(x,y,z)\,\mathbf j + F_3(x,y,z)\,\mathbf k$$

$$\mathbf A(x,y,z) = A_1(x,y,z)\,\mathbf i + A_2(x,y,z)\,\mathbf j + A_3(x,y,z)\,\mathbf k$$

The composition of $\mathbf F$ with $\mathbf A$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf F \circ \mathbf A(x,y,z) &= \mathbf F(\mathbf A(x,y,z)) \\[1ex]
&= \mathbf F(A_1(x,y,z), A_2(x,y,z), A_3(x,y,z)) \\[1ex]
&= F_1(A_1(x,y,z), A_2(x,y,z), A_3(x,y,z)) \,\mathbf i \\
&\qquad + F_2(A_1(x,y,z), A_2(x,y,z), A_3(x,y,z))\,\mathbf j \\
&\qquad + F_3(A_1(x,y,z), A_2(x,y,z), A_3(x,y,z))\,\mathbf k
\end{align*}$$

By the chain rule, the divergence of $\mathbf F\circ\mathbf A$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (\mathbf F \circ \mathbf A) &= \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial A_1} \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial A_2} \frac{\partial A_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial A_3} \frac{\partial A_3}{\partial x} \\
&\qquad + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial A_1} \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial A_2} \frac{\partial A_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial A_3} \frac{\partial A_3}{\partial y} \\
&\qquad + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial A_1} \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial A_2} \frac{\partial A_2}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial A_3} \frac{\partial A_3}{\partial z}
\end{align*}$$